# Are there any command-line HTML-to-PDF converters that can create fillable form fields?

Tags: pdf, command-line, pdf-generation, weasyprint, pdf-form

I regularly need to create PDF documents that contain fillable forms, which clients then need to be able to fill in and save using Adobe Reader. I want to automate this process, but I haven't yet come across a HTML-to-PDF converter that actually supports converting HTML form inputs to fillable PDF form inputs or otherwise adding fillable form inputs to the output PDF.

The consensus seems to be that `wkhtmltopdf` is now too old to be actively used with its lack of support for CSS3, but even the more modern converters that I've looked at - such as [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.org) and [HTMLDoc](https://www.msweet.org/htmldoc/) - don't seem to have this feature, and there are many others I've come across whose support I'm not sure of.

Is it at all possible to do this via the command-line (preferred) or programmatically?

Comment: I haven't been able to get weasyprint to do this either. Doesn't seem to be a difficult conversion as HTML has text fields already.